# PostgreSql and EF - Getting 'duplicate key' error while doing 'ToDictionary' after grouping

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Here is my query. `UserName` column is `citext`, having non-unique index on it.

```
var logs = Db.Logs
            .GroupBy(x => x.UserName)
            .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Max(m => m.Time));
```

I'm getting an exception:

> System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been
> added

I don't understand, how is it possible to be any dupe keys in resultant dictionary, if grouped values can't have dupes by design?

---

P.S.
I have an update on this. While investigating, I've looked into generated sql for `GroupBy` statement and got stuck (see below). Why `group by` interpreted as `order by` instead??

```
SELECT x."Time", x."UserName"
FROM "UserAccessLogs" AS x
ORDER BY x."UserName" NULLS FIRST
```

Comment: Do you use EF or EF Core? These are different technologies. Fix the tags.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov I'm using EF Core but I supposed there may be some common points  with EF on this issue. Never mind, I've figured that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, seems that is a kind of '*documented behavior*'. Grouping for further manipulation (*like `ToDictionary` f.e.*) requires anonymous type representation before. I rewrote my query as

```
var logs = Db.Logs
            .GroupBy(x => x.UserName)
            .Select(g => new { UserName = g.Key, Time = g.Max(m => m.Time)})
            .ToDictionary(d => d.UserName, d => d.Time);
```

and it works as expected. That's why EF was interpreting my query wrong and that's why I was getting a '*dupe keys*' error.